# Mixing XAML and code to add controls (WPF)

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a XAML file where I have defined the UI elements.
In my code-behind for the window, I add some UI elements into one of the controls I have in the XAML file, and when I run it, it does not show up my control that I have added using the C# code.

For checking purposes, I tried to remove all controls I had set up via the XAML, in my C# code - to see if the code has any effect at all.

When I run the code, the c# code bits go through removing the controls from the control I have set up in the XAML, but the window still continues to display the controls I had set up in the XAML.

What is going on that I don't understand?
Is there no way to add to controls collection of controls I have set up using XAML, from C# code?
I don't even seem to be able to simply remove the controls from my code, that I had set up in XAML.

Is there any API call I am missing that I should call when I do something to the controls setup using XAML, like Refresh() etc that we do in WinForms?

I have tried doing UpdateLayout on the control (on which I am trying to add new controls, remove from etc.), but does not seem to help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Need to see your code to help out.

Comment: A code sample is worth a thousand words. Or something.

Comment: When you add controls in code-behind, do you do this before or after IntializeComponent?